# Creating an editable grid list bound to db list in VB.NET

Tags: datagridview, combobox

I have a form with 7 combo boxes that when vales are selected and then a save button is pressed, the data is committed to the main DB and then displayed in a grid view below the fields

As I would then want users to be able to edit the data in the grid I would like it that they can click the row, which would load the data in that row back into the drop down fields, where they could then pick the correct value from the list of values in any of the dropdowns.

I'd set up a bit of code that populates the row back into the drop downs, however it's not really functional i.e. no ideas how you could do this and load the list of values as well so user could select row from data grid, then pick new values from combo box drop down.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As 
DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick
        MsgBox("Row Clicked")
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(2).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(3).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(4).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(5).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(row.Cells(6).Value.ToString)
            DateTimePicker1.Value = row.Cells(0).Value


            ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox3.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox4.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox5.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox6.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox7.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells(1).Value)
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(row.Cells(2).Value)
            ComboBox3.Items.Add(row.Cells(3).Value)
            ComboBox4.Items.Add(row.Cells(4).Value)
            ComboBox5.Items.Add(row.Cells(5).Value)
            ComboBox6.Items.Add(row.Cells(6).Value)
            ComboBox7.Items.Add(row.Cells(7).Value)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Appreciate any thoughts on how to go forward with this.

Thanks

Andrew

Edit: [Form Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DSmf.png)

Code for combo box values inserted to database.

```
Private Sub LoadDataToQuery()
    Dim myTable As New DataTable()
    'Dim MyConn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim MyCmd As New SqlCommand()
    'Dim InputDate As DateTime

    'Parameters for insert query
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@InputDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = DateTimePicker1.Value})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@staffMember", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Ward", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = ComboBox2.GetItemText(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Defecit", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = ComboBox3.GetItemText(ComboBox3.SelectedItem)})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Reason", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = ComboBox4.GetItemText(ComboBox4.SelectedItem)})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Band", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = ComboBox5.GetItemText(ComboBox5.SelectedItem)})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AuthoriserName5", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = ComboBox6.GetItemText(ComboBox6.SelectedItem)})
    MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AuthoriserName6", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = ComboBox7.GetItemText(ComboBox7.SelectedItem)})


    'Open conection and run query
    myConn.Open()
    MyCmd.Connection = myConn
    'Create insert statement
    MyCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OvertimeAuthorisationMain VALUES(@InputDate, @staffMember, @Ward, @Defecit, @Reason, @Band, @AuthoriserName5, @AuthoriserName6)"
    MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MyCmd.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: You are asking many questions and some may be considered opinionated with words like… _”thoughts on how to go forward with this”_ ... Stackoverflow is not a “write the code” for me website. There are surely numerous ways to “go forward” and you will most likely get a better response if you show the code and screen shots of what you currently have and what you want to change. Try what you think is best to “go forward” and if it doesn’t work as you expect, then that would be a question to ask here. You may want to peruse the SO [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Ok, I'll try and edit the question so it is more targeted on the actual issue.

Comment: From what I can decipher, there is a grid with 8 columns of data. It appears the first column is a date value. Then above the grid are 7 combo boxes? If the user clicks on a “row” header, you want that row to populate the combo boxes above? I am not sure if I understand this layout, however, considering you want to populate the combo boxes when the user clicks on a row header… is there some reason you don’t make the columns in the GRID “combo boxes”?

Comment: The code looks odd in a sense that when the user clicks a row header, the code grabs that row, displays some messages, sets a date time picker value, then “clears” all the combo boxes of ALL items? Then “adds” the values from the grid cells into each combo box containing the values from the “selected” row. This seems odd because after you “clear” each combo box and then “add” the value from the grid… then the combo box will only contain ONE (1) item. If the user clicks on the combo box, there will only be ONE choice, defeating the purpose of the combo box

Comment: I am guessing that if you DO NOT “clear” the combo boxes of values and instead simply set each combo box to the value from the grid like… `ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString()` … obviously it would be wise to check for both `null` AND “valid” values if the user can “type” text into that cell.

Comment: @johng Making the columns combo boxes in grid would be ideal, I found a way to do it, however it made every row, on one column, a combo box. What you mentioned about the combo box (On the form) only containing one data value is one of the issues. I preload the form combo boxes with data from look up tables in Database, being able to edit in datagrid row would eliminate the need to pull the selected row values into the form combo boxes, however have the issues as described with getting all the columns on the selected datagrid row to change to combo boxes.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you show an example of the problem you are having?

Comment: @johng Basically when user puts in new entry from drop down boxes on form, that then end up in the grid list, how can these entries then be edited after being committed? That's all it is.

Comment: What do you mean by … _”how can these entries then be edited after being committed?”_ …“committed” to what? If the values are in the grid, then I assume the user could “edit” those values as they choose. Again, I am having a very difficult time “visualizing” how the combo boxes and the grid are related. Is there a “button” on the form to allow the user to “add” rows to the grid from the values in the combo boxes? I suggest you take a screen shot of what you have and what you are trying to achieve. Along with any “pertinent” code, like the code that “adds” rows to the grid.

Comment: @johng The values in the grid are committed to database, The user picks values from the form combo boxes then presses save, this then calls sub to set parameters then run insert query for data.

Comment: @johng I've added an image of the form to the first post and the code that is called when you click the save button on the form. So once this is done is the point where I am trying to find out is it then possible to click no the row in the datagrid to be able to edit any of the cells in the row that was clicked in.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there may be a better way to do this, however, given what I can decipher would go something like…

There are numerous `ComboBoxes` above a `DataGridView`. Each of the grid’s columns correspond to a particular `ComboBox`. If the user clicks on a row in the grid, the corresponding combo boxes are to be set to the same values that are in the “selected” row in the grid. In addition, after the user “selects” a row in the grid and the combo boxes get filled with “that” rows data, THEN… the user can then “change” some values in the combo boxes, then click a “Save” button to save the selected combo box values into the “selected” row in the grid. In addition, these changes should also be updated in the data base. I hope I have this right.

That is a lot for a question on SO and I will attempt to help break some of it down to manageable pieces.

Below is a picture of the form the code below manages. There is a form with a Save `Button`, five (5) `ComboBoxes` and a `DataGridView`. There is a Data Base Table (TestCombos) used that has the following schema…

```
RecordNumber    int PrimaryKey – not null
Member  nvarchar(50) - null
Ward    nvarchar(50) - null
Deficit int - null
Reason  nvarchar(50) - null
Band    nvarchar(50) - null
```

[image]

From your posted code, I do not see “where” the code is “Updating” the data base with the selected row’s changes. The `LoadDataToQuery` method appears to (awkwardly) “Insert” a “new” row from the combo boxes. I am betting the reason the “update” code is missing is because from what I can see in the code… How would you KNOW “which” row in the data base table to “update”? In other words, If the user “selected” a row, changed the combo boxes, then clicked the save button. We would know which “row” has changed since it is the selected row in the grid and from it, we could get which row to pick in the grids `DataSource` `DataTable`… however, we would not necessarily KNOW which row in the data base table to update.

I do not see anything “Unique” that would identify one row from another. I can see a “Date” being used, but I can also imagine numerous rows with the same date. Point being you need some unique identifier to point to the proper row in the Data Base Table. This is why I added a “RecordNumber” column in the table and made it a primary key without nulls and obviously, no duplicates. This way when the code needs to “update” a record in the data base table, we will know exactly which one.

It would not be necessary to show this column to the user, however, you will need to make sure that when a “New” record/row is added, that the `RecordNumber` is unique. In this example the code simply uses the row number in the table as the record number, if the user “adds” a row, the `RecordNumber` for that row will be the number of rows in the table + 1. This will work for this example; however, I DO NOT recommend using this strategy. If you “delete” rows, this will cause problems. Therefore, I recommend another approach to get a unique key for new rows.

Having each row with a unique key will make “updating” the values in the data base table much easier and less error prone using a WHERE clause in the query to identify the proper row to update.

Another thing missing in your post is “what” values are you adding to the combo boxes? The strange `RowHeaderMouseClick` event appears to… Grab the selected `row`, then outputs some messages from the selected row’s cells. Then, for unknown reasons, ALL the combo boxes are CLEARED of items? WHY? … Then the selected row’s cells are “added” to the corresponding combo boxes items? … Basically, every time the user clicks on a row header, then, whatever value was in the combo box is deleted, and the selected rows cell values in the grid are added to the combo boxes. Which will mean that the combo boxes will only have ONE (1) value and the user will never see a combo box with “multiple” values.

It is unknown if you want the user to be able to “add” items to the combo boxes and “usually” combo boxes have FIXED values that do not change; however, I have seen situations where items need to be added to the combo box. Unfortunately, this example does NOT allow the user to “Add” new items.

Given this, I will assume that you want the combo boxes to contain… “ALL the Unique Values for Its Corresponding Column in The Grid”. Example, In the “Staff Member” combo box, you would want ALL the “different” Staff Member values in the grid without duplicates. If you know a pre-defined set of values you want to use then you can add those values first. However, it is possible that there MAY be a value in the data that is NOT one of the pre-defined values. Those values will NOT show up in the combo box unless you add them.

Therefore, to “almost” guarantee that ALL the values are in the combo box, you should first add your pre-defined values, then check the data for any values that are NOT part of the pre-defined values. If you find one, then add it to the combo box as it is also in the data. In this example, there are NO pre-defined values for the combo boxes. The code simply loops through the data and grabs the distinct/unique values from each column.

You could query your data base for this data, however, the `GetUniqueDataFromSource(colIndex As Int32, dt As DataTable, type As Int32)` method below is a simple method that takes a column index to identify which column of data we want to get, a `DataTable` that holds the data and an int value to identify the “type” of list we want to return, either string or int.

First the “type” is checked and a new List is created. A zero (0) and empty string are added to the combo boxes to facilitate adding new rows. A a simple loop through the data table rows to add each item to the list. If the list already “contains” that value, it is NOT added to the list (Duplicate). Lastly the list is sorted and then returned. This method will be used to set each combo boxes `DataSource` to the appropriate values for its corresponding column in the grid and will be called ONCE for each combo box when the form loads.

```
Private Function GetUniqueDataFromSource(colIndex As Int32, dt As DataTable, type As Int32)
  Dim dataList
  If (type = 2) Then
    dataList = New List(Of Int32)
    dataList.Add(0)
  Else
    dataList = New List(Of String)
    dataList.Add("")
  End If
  Dim curItem
  For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    curItem = row.ItemArray(colIndex)
    If (Not dataList.Contains(curItem)) Then
      dataList.Add(curItem)
    End If
  Next
  dataList.Sort()
  Return dataList
End Function
```

This should “populate” the combo boxes with the proper data. However, if the user selects a row, the combo boxes will not reflect the values from the “selected” row. To help, a method called `UpdateCombosFromGrid()` may be useful. This method takes no arguments and simply sets each combo box value to the value that is from the currently “selected” row. The code checks if there is a selected row, then sets the appropriate combo box with the corresponding value and type from the grid. Bear in mind, the grids `SelectionMode` MUST be set to some “full row” select. Otherwise the `DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count` will always return zero (0).

```
Private Sub UpdateCombosFromGrid()
  If (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) Then
    Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
    Dim value = 0
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells("Member").Value
    ComboBox2.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells("Ward").Value
    Integer.TryParse(selectedRow.Cells("Deficit").Value.ToString(), value)
    ComboBox3.SelectedItem = value
    ComboBox4.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells("Reason").Value
    ComboBox5.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells("Band").Value
  End If
End Sub
```

We can use the above method to set the combo boxes values when the form loads and also when the user changes the grid selection. If the user selects a different row, then the combo boxes will reflect that change. However, if the user selects the “New” row, the last “empty” row in the grid as seen in the picture, then we want to “clear” the combo boxes. This is not really necessary; however, it would be a good signal to the user that they CAN ADD new rows. If the selected row is NOT the new row, then call the above method.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
  If (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) Then
    Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
    If (selectedRow.IsNewRow) Then
      ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ""
      ComboBox2.SelectedItem = ""
      ComboBox3.SelectedItem = 0
      ComboBox4.SelectedItem = ""
      ComboBox5.SelectedItem = ""
    Else
      UpdateCombosFromGrid()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

This should take care of updating the combo boxes to reflect the grids “selected” row when the user selects different rows.

Next is the “Save” button and it really has to do two things, first we need to “Update” the “selected” row in the grid AND also “update” that row to the data base. To help, a method that does the reverse of the `UpdateCombosFromGrid()` method. As the name implies, the `UpdateSelectedRowFromCombos()` method, takes the values FROM the combo boxes and sets those values to the “selected” row in the grid.

```
Private Sub UpdateSelectedRowFromCombos()
  If (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) Then
    Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
    Dim value = 0
    selectedRow.Cells("Member").Value = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
    selectedRow.Cells("Ward").Value = ComboBox2.SelectedValue
    Integer.TryParse(ComboBox3.SelectedValue, value)
    selectedRow.Cells("Deficit").Value = value
    selectedRow.Cells("Reason").Value = ComboBox4.SelectedValue
    selectedRow.Cells("Band").Value = ComboBox5.SelectedValue
  End If
End Sub
```

This will take care of getting the new values into the grid whether it be an update to an existing row, or adding a new row. However, “updating” a row in the data base table and “adding” a row are two different queries. I am confident you could make one method to do this, however I will make two different methods. Both methods take a `DataRow` and either “update” an existing row or “insert” a new row.

```
Private Sub UpdateDB_WithRow(rowToUpdate As DataRow)
  Dim connString = "Server = localhost; Database = TestDB; Trusted_Connection = True;"
  Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd = New StringBuilder("UPDATE TestCombos SET Member = @Member, Ward = @Ward, ") 
    cmd.Append("Deficit = @Deficit, Reason = @Reason, Band = @Band ")
    cmd.Append("WHERE RecordNumber = @RecordNumber")
    conn.Open()
    Using da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
      da.UpdateCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
      da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member", rowToUpdate("Member"))
      da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ward", rowToUpdate("Ward"))
      da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deficit", rowToUpdate("Deficit"))
      da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", rowToUpdate("Reason"))
      da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Band", rowToUpdate("Band"))
      da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordNumber", rowToUpdate("RecordNumber"))
      da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = cmd.ToString()
      da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
  End Using
End Sub
```

Insert new row…

```
Private Sub InsertNewRowToDB(rowToUpdate As DataRow)
  Dim connString = "Server = localhost; Database = TestDB; Trusted_Connection = True;"
  Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd = New StringBuilder("INSERT INTO TestCombos Values (@RecordNumber, @Member, @Ward, @Deficit, @Reason, @Band)")
    conn.Open()
    Using da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
      da.InsertCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member", rowToUpdate("Member"))
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ward", rowToUpdate("Ward"))
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deficit", rowToUpdate("Deficit"))
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", rowToUpdate("Reason"))
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Band", rowToUpdate("Band"))
      da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordNumber", rowToUpdate("RecordNumber"))
      da.InsertCommand.CommandText = cmd.ToString()
      da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
  End Using
End Sub
```

With a method to update the selected row and a method to update/add the row to the data base, the save event may look something like…

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
  Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
  Dim newRow
  If (selectedRow.IsNewRow) Then
    newRow = ds.Tables("TestCombos").Rows.Add()
    newRow("RecordNumber") = ds.Tables("TestCombos").Rows.Count
    newRow("Member") = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    newRow("Ward") = ComboBox2.SelectedItem
    newRow("Deficit") = ComboBox3.SelectedItem
    newRow("Reason") = ComboBox4.SelectedItem
    newRow("Band") = ComboBox5.SelectedItem
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(selectedRow.Index - 1).Cells(0)
    InsertNewRowToDB(newRow)
  Else
    UpdateSelectedRowFromCombos()
    Dim tableRowIndex = ds.Tables("TestCombos").Rows.IndexOf(DirectCast(selectedRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row)
    UpdateDB_WithRow(ds.Tables("TestCombos").Rows(tableRowIndex))
  End If
End Sub
```

A method to get the data from the data base…

```
Private Sub GetDataFromDB()
  ds = New DataSet()
  Dim connString = "Server = localhost; Database = TestDB; Trusted_Connection = True;"
  Dim query = "select * from TestCombos"
  Using conn = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "TestCombos")
    conn.Close()
  End Using
End Sub
```

Next, we need a method to set up each combo boxes values after the data has been loaded. We can use the `GetUniqueDataFromSource` method described earlier and it may look like below…

```
Private Sub SetComboBoxValues()
  ComboBox1.DataSource = GetUniqueDataFromSource(1, ds.Tables("TestCombos"), 1)
  ComboBox2.DataSource = GetUniqueDataFromSource(2, ds.Tables("TestCombos"), 1)
  ComboBox3.DataSource = GetUniqueDataFromSource(3, ds.Tables("TestCombos"), 2)
  ComboBox4.DataSource = GetUniqueDataFromSource(4, ds.Tables("TestCombos"), 1)
  ComboBox5.DataSource = GetUniqueDataFromSource(5, ds.Tables("TestCombos"), 1)
End Sub
```

Finally, putting this all together in the form load event…

```
Dim ds As DataSet

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  GetDataFromDB()
  DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("TestCombos")
  SetComboBoxValues()
  UpdateCombosFromGrid()
  DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

I hope this help. And It is possible to make the grid full of combo boxes, however, that would be another question. Good Luck!